# Copy Title Attribute Value and Insert as InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Auto-Generated Code in our CMS based Website like this

```
<td class="photogalleryItem">
<a onclick="myLightbox.start(this);return false;" rel="lightbox[33136]" href="image1.jpg" title="Test">
<img border="0" src="image1.jpg" alt="Test">
</a>
</td>
```

I want to copy that href title or Image alt `value` and insert as below

```
<td class="photogalleryItem">
   <!--Like This <h3 style="text-align:center;">Test</h3>-->
    <a onclick="myLightbox.start(this);return false;" rel="lightbox[33136]" href="image1.jpg" title="Test">
    <img border="0" src="image1.jpg" alt="Test">
</a>
</td>
```

How can i do that in using javascript or Jquery.

This code is in Gallery page. so this is repeating for every images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have single `td` with class `photogalleryItem`,You can use:

```
$('.photogalleryItem').append('<h3 style="text-align:center;">'+ $('.photogalleryItem').find('img').attr('alt')+'</h3>');
```

If you have multiple `td` with class `photogalleryItem`:

```
 $('.photogalleryItem').each(function(){
      $(this).append('<h3 style="text-align:center;">'+ $(this).find('img').attr('alt')+'</h3>');
 })
```

Comment: It Worked. and I used prepend to make it top.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$('.photogalleryItem').each(function () {
    $(this).prepend('<h3 style="text-align:center;">' + $(this).find('img').attr('alt') + '</h3>');
});
```

Comment: Load Function didnt work somehow. but `prepend` was helpful to make it top in image.